# RegEx: Finding semicolon between double quotes

Tags: regex

I am just starting with regular expressions. I need to find all the cases in the text, where there is semicolon in the string between double quotes. So I am searching for the cases like

```
"something;something"
"something ; something"
"something; something"
"something ;something"
```

I found code to find strings between double quotes:

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

Can you help me modify it so I will find cases like I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [negated character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) class where you can add what you don't want to match. If there can be only 1 semicolon in the string, then you can also add that to the character class, else you could use `[^"\r\n]*` where there can be multiple occurrences of `;`

`"([^"\r\n;]*;[^";\r\n]*)"`

That would match

- `"` Match literally
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[^"\r\n;]*` Match 0+ times not a `"`, newline or semicolon
  - `;` Match literally
  - `[^"\r\n;]*` Match 0+ times not a `"`, newline or semicolon
- `)` Close capturing group
- `"` Match literally

Your value is in the first capturing group.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EMqrjV/2)

If you don't want to match just a semicolon between double quotes you could prepend a negative lookahead:

`(?!";")"([^"\r\n;]*;[^";\r\n]*)"`

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Can you modify it so it ommits cases like  ";"  ? That means it ommits cases where there is just semicolon between double quotes, without any characters or spaces. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = <<<INPUT
a
"something;something"
b
"something ; something"
c
"something; something"
d
"something ;something"
e
INPUT;

preg_match_all("/\"([^\"]+;[^\"]+)\"/im", $input, $m);

print_r($m);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "something;something"
            [1] => "something ; something"
            [2] => "something; something"
            [3] => "something ;something"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => something;something
            [1] => something ; something
            [2] => something; something
            [3] => something ;something
        )

)
*/
```